# How to do git submodules and why to use git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have found a GitHub project and it uses git submodules.

What is the usage of git submodules?

How to create git submodules?

How do they differ from subtree?

[image: GitSubModule]

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Furthermore, it doesn't show very much research effort. A search for `git submodule vs subtree` generates *lots* of results, and Google even suggested that search to me while I was typing `submodule`.

Comment: The best way to use submodules: Not at all. (Make the second repo generate a build artifact you can rely on)

Comment: @Daenyth - Yeah..that's also correct ! But do you think if there is any drawback of using submodules ?

Comment: @Manju The workflow is painful when you use submodules. The only argument for using them (imo) is if you don't have a way to manage build artifacts, so that dependency management is harder than using a submodule.

Comment: @Daenyth - How do you compare the harder workflow of submodules with subtrees ?

Comment: @Manju submodules and subtrees have different purposes. Submodules are for when you want to have two separate repositories with one used inside the other. Subtree is for when you have two repos and you want to make one repo's contents a permanent part of the first repo.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Git Submodule:*

A submodule in a git repository is like a sub-directory which is really a separate git repository in its own right.  This is a useful feature when you have a project in git which depends on a particular versions of other projects

*Git Subtree:*

Git subtree allows you to insert any repository as a sub-directory of another one.the sub-directory would become permanent part of the super project

*Git Subtree and submodule:*

A subtree merge permanently integrates the contents and history of the subtree into the parent repository at the subtree of the merge.

A submodule is simply a reference to a specific commit in the submodule. A history  of changes to referenced commit are kept in the parent module, but no contents or history of the submodule are tracked in the parent module.

*Configure Git submodule:*

- You have a project -- call it MyWebApp that already has a github repo
- You want to use the jquery repository in your project
- You want to pull the jquery repo into your project as a submodule.
- Submodules are really, really easy to reference and use. Assuming you already have MyWebApp set up as a repo, from terminal issue these commands:

  1. `cd MyWebApp`
  2. `git submodule add git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git externals/jquery`
     This will create a directory named *externals/jquery* and link it to the *github jquery repository*. Now we just need to *init* the submodule and clone the code to it:
  3. `git submodule update --init --recursive`
     You should now have all the latest code cloned into the submodule. If the jquery repo changes and you want to pull the latest code down, just issue the submodule update command again.

     *Please note:*

     I typically have a number of external repositories in my projects, so I always group the repos under an **externals** directory.