# How to create a git project and allow to use as subprojects

Tags: git, composer-php, subproject

I have created a PHP framework, and I want to reuse some framework components in other projects as Laravel does, using composer.
For example, my framework skeleton has a folder called HTTP, this component has HttpRequest, HttpResponse, etc.. and I want to use the HTTP component of my framework in other projects.

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "MyFramework/Http": "dev-master",
        "predis/predis": "1.1.1"
    },
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `git submodules`.

Please read here for more info:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial

[How to do git sub modules and why to use git sub module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790481/how-to-do-git-sub-modules-and-why-to-use-git-sub-module)